# Configuring Google Translate on Windows

Tags: python, google-translate

I want to use Google Translate API in my Python application and I have read through the documentation and I have set my Service Account and downloaded the JSON file now according to the documentation I am supposed to run a:

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>
```

Now I am doing my development on a Windows machine and I tried using the

```
>setx GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS "<path_to_service_account_file>"
```

It generated a success however when I tried to create a translate object I kept getting the following error:

```
from google.cloud import translate
trans = translate.Client()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\achim\Envs\expert-farmer\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\translate\client.py", line 66, in __init__
    super(Client, self).__init__(credentials=credentials, _http=_http)
  File "C:\Users\achim\Envs\expert-farmer\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\client.py", line 128, in __init__
    credentials = get_credentials()
  File "C:\Users\achim\Envs\expert-farmer\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\credentials.py", line 39, in get_credentials
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
  File "C:\Users\achim\Envs\expert-farmer\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_default.py", line 282, in default
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or
explicitly create credential and re-run the application. For more
information, please see
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.
```

Comment: Does `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>` and then running your python application work?

Comment: i tried that but i got another error

Comment: rmeertens thank you hey i tried it without the quotes and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question was resolved in the comments! Next time don't use quote characters around your command.

```
setx GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS <path_to_service_account_file>
```